# How to register for foreground notifications for Watchkit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, watchos, foregroundnotification

I want to get notified when the watch app enters foreground. How to register for "willEnterForegroundNotification" in SwiftUI. Following is the code to register for the same in UIKit.

```
Text("Hello, World!")
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
        print("Moving back to the foreground!")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On watchOS 7 and above

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: WKExtension.applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification)
```